# Article + then + noun

Tags: grammaticality

I'm trying to write the following sentence:
This understanding comes as a contrast with **a, then, dominant belief system**...
 Can I use the adverb 'then' between the article and its noun as in the case above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, without the commas (unless it is apparent, see edit 2 below).

As pointed out in the comments, you are using "then" as an adverb as in definition 1 of [Marriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then)

> **then** (adverb)
>
> 1 : at that time
>
> 2a : soon after that : next in order of time
>
> *walked to the door, then turned*
>
> b : following next after in order of position, narration, or enumeration : being next in a series
>
> *first came the clowns, and then came the elephants*
>
> c : in addition : besides
>
> *then there is the interest to be paid*
>
> 3a : as a necessary consequence
>
> *if the angles are equal, then the complements are equal*
>
> b(1) : in that case
>
> take it, then, if you want it so much
>
> (2) —used after but to qualify or offset a preceding statement
>
> *she lost the race, but then she never really expected to win*
>
> c : according to that : as may be inferred
>
> *your mind is made up, then*
>
> d : as it appears : by way of summing up
>
> *the cause of the accident, then, is established*

but it may also be used as an adjective

> **then** (adjective)
>
> : existing or acting at or belonging to the time mentioned

Edit 2:

You could leave the commas there in the following case (from [grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp))

> **Rule 5.** Use commas to set off nonessential words, clauses, and phrases

as pointed out in the comments, but I would take them out in this case since the meaning of the sentence would be different without the 'then'.

Comment: In the OP's example, it's an adverb modifying an adjective. _The then Sen. Kennedy_ = adjective.

Comment: @KarlG Ah yes, now you mention it...

Comment: *Cf* “without he commas”: I don’t see a problem with the word *then* being used parenthetically, given the right context.

Comment: @Lawrence Hmmmm, I suppose so, but I would argue it wouldn't work in this case, since without the 'then' the meaning of the sentence would be changed. Nevertheless I shall add it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. What I meant was that the parenthetical use of “then” can pointedly highlight (or alternatively, soften) the ‘is no longer’ aspect, compared to the non-parenthetical version. “The then governor” states something clinically. “The, *then*, governor”, with a stress on “then”, emphasises the fact the person is no longer the governor. If *then* is spoken more softly, it becomes more of a concession or aside. I don’t think making “then” parenthetical changes its part-of-speech.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Especially thank you for this comment: [but it may also be used as an adjective then (adjective): existing or acting at or belonging to the time mentioned]  I wanted to use then to refer to a time period (the past). What do I do in this case; do I leave it as it is or do I omit the commas?

Comment: @Sophia While I would advise against it, Lawrence is of the opinion that it could be used for emphasis (if I understand correctly), but I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: @Lawrence Would you agree with me if I said it can't have the commas in the OPs sense of the phrase?

Comment: With her recent comment sounding like the intent is to adopt a neutral tone, yes, the commas should be dropped. As the question stands, however, the commas can legitimately serve to highlight the loss of dominance.

Comment: @Lawrence I wouldn't be surprised for it to be used stylistically, but can't find it mentioned in any rule books. Do you have a reference for me to read up on, purely out of interest?

Comment: @Sophia We both agree you should use it without commas.

Comment: @Sophia You're very welcome. Feel free to mark the solution as accepted to help people looking for the similar answers and voting the comments up once you achieve the privilege.

Comment: Sorry I've never really used this website properly before. How do I mark your solution as accepted? I only found these four options at the top: share edit delete flag - or Add comment or Help at the end. Not sure how... sorry...

Comment: @Sophia No worries! You'll find it to the side of the answer, under the amount of votes

Comment: Sorry, this wasn’t something I got from a rule book. It’s from knowing and using the language personally. You can try asking about rules of thumb at [ell.se].